# How to set a relative path for images?

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

How do I set a relative path for images?

```
public class Currency2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton USA_btn, INDIA_btn, DUBAI_btn, AUSTRALIA_btn, ITALY_btn, MALAYSIA_btn, SINGAPORE_btn, ENGLAND_btn, SAUDI_btn, QATAR_btn;
    public Currency2 cr2;
    ImagePanel panel_secondframe;
    Border thickBorder;
    public Currency2(){
        super("Currency Converter");
        this.InitializeComponents();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String Object = e.getActionCommand();
        if(Object.equals("USA")){
            Currency_USA cus = new Currency_USA(this);
            cus.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("INDIA")){
            Currency_INDIA cin = new Currency_INDIA(this);
            cin.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("DUBAI")){
            Currency_DUBAI cdu = new Currency_DUBAI(this);
            cdu.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("ITALY")){
           Currency_ITALY cit = new Currency_ITALY(this);
           cit.setVisible(true);
           this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("ENGLAND")){
           Currency_ENGLAND cei = new Currency_ENGLAND(this);
           cei.setVisible(true);
           this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("AUSTRALIA")){
            Currency_AUSTRALIA cau = new Currency_AUSTRALIA(this);
            cau.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("MALAYSIA")){
           Currency_MALAYSIA cma = new Currency_MALAYSIA(this);
           cma.setVisible(true);
           this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("SINGAPORE")){
           Currency_SINGAPORE csi = new Currency_SINGAPORE(this);
           csi.setVisible(true);
           this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("SAUDI")){
           Currency_SAUDI cssi = new Currency_SAUDI(this);
           cssi.setVisible(true);
           this.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(Object.equals("QATAR")){
           Currency_QATAR cqa = new Currency_QATAR(this);
           cqa.setVisible(true);
           this.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
private void InitializeComponents() {
    this.panel_secondframe = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("E:\\programing \\JAVA\\new netbean pro\\currency\\src\\newpackage\\image of currency converter\\secondframe.png").getImage());
    this.getContentPane().add(panel_secondframe);
    this.pack();

    this.thickBorder = new LineBorder(Color.black);

    this.USA_btn = new JButton("USA");
    this.USA_btn.setBounds(136, 35, 89, 23);
    this.USA_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.USA_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(USA_btn);

    this.INDIA_btn = new JButton("INDIA");
    this.INDIA_btn.setBounds(136, 65, 89, 23);
    this.INDIA_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.INDIA_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(INDIA_btn);

    this.DUBAI_btn = new JButton("DUBAI");
    this.DUBAI_btn.setBounds(136, 95, 89, 23);
    this.DUBAI_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.DUBAI_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(DUBAI_btn);

    this.ITALY_btn = new JButton("ITALY");
    this.ITALY_btn.setBounds(136, 125, 89, 23);
    this.ITALY_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.ITALY_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(ITALY_btn);

    this.SAUDI_btn = new JButton("SAUDI");
    this.SAUDI_btn.setBounds(136, 155, 89, 23);
    this.SAUDI_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.SAUDI_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(SAUDI_btn);

    this.QATAR_btn = new JButton("QATAR");
    this.QATAR_btn.setBounds(136, 185, 89, 23);
    this.QATAR_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.QATAR_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(QATAR_btn);

    this.ENGLAND_btn = new JButton("ENGLAND");
    this.ENGLAND_btn.setBounds(129, 215, 102, 23);
    this.ENGLAND_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.ENGLAND_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(ENGLAND_btn);

    this.AUSTRALIA_btn = new JButton("AUSTRALIA");
    this.AUSTRALIA_btn.setBounds(129, 245, 102, 23);
    this.AUSTRALIA_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.AUSTRALIA_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(AUSTRALIA_btn);

    this.MALAYSIA_btn = new JButton("MALAYSIA");
    this.MALAYSIA_btn.setBounds(129, 275, 102, 23);
    this.MALAYSIA_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.MALAYSIA_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(MALAYSIA_btn);

    this.SINGAPORE_btn = new JButton("SINGAPORE");
    this.SINGAPORE_btn.setBounds(129, 305, 102, 23);
    this.SINGAPORE_btn.addActionListener(this);
    this.SINGAPORE_btn.setBorder(thickBorder);
    this.panel_secondframe.add(SINGAPORE_btn);

    this.add(this.panel_secondframe);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you've tried and give detail on what exactly you're trying to do in the question, instead of the title.

Comment: To give you a step in the right direction, you'll need to pack the image into your JAR (if you're building one) or place it on your classpath, and use a resource path instead of a filesystem path. I'm not entirely sure how this would work with a Swing `ImageIcon`, though.

Comment: Giving a variable the same name as a class, such as `Object`, is a bad practice that is going to create significant difficulty when maintaining the code (as well as difficulty for Stack Overflow readers who are trying to analyze it).  Always start variable names with a lowercase letter, unless they're static final fields.

Comment: There's examples in the [tag:embedded-resource] tag under [learn more](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 2):

To set a relative path replace with,

```
this.panel_secondframe = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon(".\\src\\newpackage\\image of currency converter\\secondframe.png").getImage());
```

Answer (score 1):

Java class `Class` has a `static` method `getResourceAsStream(path)` which is able to load common resources from the package structure of the application itself. This is rather useful and common to use in your situation.

Suppose you have your images inside `com.yourpackage.icons` (so `com/yourpackage/icons` as your real path, then you can use

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/yourpackage/icons/imagename.png")));
```

Comment: getResourceAsStream is not a static method.  Also, ImageIO isn't really needed, since there is an ImageIcon constructor which accepts a URL.

Comment: ImageIO throws an error if it can't read the image file.  The ImageIcon constructor doesn't throw an error.